# On a card view created dynamically, how can I remove individual cards if a delete button specific to a card is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

This function is called each time button is pressed and it adds a new card having the name assigned to that card. How can I remove a specific card when the 'x' icon of the card is pressed?

// function to create individual cards on button press

```
public void cardview1()
{
    text2 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_name);
    dev_id1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_id);

    cardview2 = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
    cardview2.setFocusable(false);
    cardview2.setClickable(false);

    layoutparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutparams1.setMargins(19, 83, 19, 0);

    lay1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    layoutparams2 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 115);
    lay2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams2);
    lay2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    layoutparams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lay6 = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay6.setWeightSum(12);
    lay6.setLayoutParams(layoutparams3);
    lay6.setPadding(10,40,0,0);
    lay6.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    cardview2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    cardview2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2fffffff"));
    cardview2.setMinimumHeight(330);
    cardview2.addView(lay1);

    dev_text1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    dev_text1.setText(dev_name1.getText().toString().trim()+"  ");
    dev_text1.setPadding(20, 15,0,0);
    dev_text1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 26);
    dev_text1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    dev_text1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

    sw0 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    sw0.setText("  X");
    sw0.setTextSize(20);
    sw0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    sw0.setBackgroundResource(0);
    sw0.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    sw0.setPadding(0,0,0,5);
    sw0.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70));

    lay1.addView(lay2);
    lay1.addView(lay6);
    lay2.addView(dev_text1);
    lay2.addView(sw0);
    ahomeLayout.removeView(atv);
    ahomeLayout.addView(cardview2);

    saveInPref();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to somewhere store the Ids or the Cardviwes themselves and then give the delete button the ID, so when its clicked It will give you the ID of the clicked card and you then can remove the card.

Comment: I had stored individual IDs in an array and retrieving it using sharedpreferences. Now each card is having a textview field name who's value is set using array elements. But how to remove a specific card even if I have name set on the card's textview field?